# Navigating to view embedded in navigation stack results in extra top space

Tags: swiftui

I have a tabbed app where each tab in embedded into a NavigationView(). In one of the tabs I use a navigation link to navigate to another view that is embedded inside a navigation stack, and in doing so the view appears with a lot of excess area at the top (about 1/3 of the top of the screen Is just blank).

I tried hiding the navigation bar back button but that didn't work. The only thing that worked is removing the view from the navigation stack. But this view needs the navigation stack to navigation to a different view. If I try to navigate to the TestScreen in view 2 with the navigation stack removed then the view will navigate for a second and then navigate back right away (as if the screen crashed).

I'm also not sure why it auto navigates back when there is no navigation stack. I'd appreciate some help in figuring out why there is excess space or why the view pops back when trying to navigate.

```
struct View1: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink{
                    View2()
                } label: {
                    Text("Nav")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct View2: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationStack {
                VStack {
                    NavigationLink{
                        TextView()
                    } label: {
                        Text("go")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You only need 1 NavigationView/Stack at the very top. Get rid of the NavigationViews the Stack is a replacement